# Error on first load in NextJs 13 app with Tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm building a small Next 13 app with Tailwind for a client. The problem I encounter is that whenever I open the app in vs-code, on first load,  I get a bunch of errors. Some functionality like showing menus on hover as well as click events on images don't work. Only after page refresh or deleting the .next folder and emptying the browsers cache everything works fine.The first error message is an "uncaught syntaxerror: Invalid or unexpected token", points to the .next static layout.css file. In the console several other problems are described referring to Hydration problems and ChunckLoad issues. What causes this error?

Update!
When I delete the browser history and cached files the error is gone.
After running once in the browser and opening the app again the error is back?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by refactoring the app. The navigation bar menu in the header was created by importing static data (array of objects) locally.I imported the data client-side like in react at first which resulted in the error, now I fetched the data in a server component and then imported that component into the client component. I know that that is not possible in Next 13 but there is a workaround by passing a Server Component as prop to a Client Component. Now the error is gone and everything works fine.

Described in the next docs as:
"Since Client Components are rendered after Server Components, you cannot import a Server Component into a Client Component module (since it would require a new request back to the server, hence the refresh I needed to make everything work). Instead, you can pass a Server Component as props to a Client Component."